# Mismatched types error: expected `char`, found reference

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

the code snippet is:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
  
fn main() {
    let dna = String::from("ACCCX");
    let dict: HashSet<char> = vec!['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'].into_iter().collect();
    println!("{}", dna.chars().all(|&x| dict.contains(x)));

}
```

the error shown in compilation is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:37
  |
6 |     println!("{}", dna.chars().all(|&x| dict.contains(x)));
  |                                     ^--
  |                                     ||
  |                                     |expected due to this
  |                                     expected `char`, found reference
  |                                     help: did you mean `x`: `&char`
  |
  = note:   expected type `char`
          found reference `&_`
```

Not sure why `&x` cannot be inferred as `&char` and the links I referred to are:

1. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all
2. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.contains

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Rust, but my approach here would be to try a bunch of permutations of where to put the `&`. Try using just `|x|`. Try adding one in front of the `x` argument. Try having both there...

Comment: @Lagerbaer Flailing around in symbol soup can be a way to get your code compiling, though understanding why one way works and another way doesn't keeps you from flailing in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a bit confusing, essentially it is backwards.

```
dna.chars().all(|&x| dict.contains(x)));
```

String::chars returns a `char`, not `&char`, and HashSet::contains expects a reference to the type it contains, so `&char`. However, closure `|&x| dict.contains(x)` expects a reference to some type.
It is a little confusing, but `&argument_name` in function parameters essentially performs pattern matching on incoming parameter, dereferencing it. It is the same as writing `|(a, b)|` for a closure that takes a two element tuple and immediately destructures it into two variables.
So really the message should be `Expected reference &_, found char`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just went to the Rust playground and did what I suggested: First I removed the `&` from your `|&x|`. Then the compiler complained that the `contains(x)` wasn't a reference, so I added a `&` there:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
  
fn main() {
    let dna = String::from("ACCCX");
    let dict: HashSet<char> = vec!['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'].into_iter().collect();
    println!("{}", dna.chars().all(|x| dict.contains(&x)));

}
```

That compiles and prints "false" because X isn't in the hash set.

Comment: thanks for the reply and just find that too. Also, find another example pretty interesting: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#examples-34. 

If you also remove the `&` from `|&x|` and now the compiler will yell again since this time it expects `|&x|`.

I can follow error msg and adjust but when in closure it should be `|x|` and when is `|&x|`? I'm open to discussion and enlightenment

Comment: @OtterMan the difference is that one yields *values* `.chars()` -> `char`, while the other yields *references* `.iter()` -> `&T`. And `|x|` will work for *both*, as long as you use `char`/`&T` correctly within the closure.